# Loop: Load individual image pixels NOT full image?

Tags: image, matlab, loops, pixel

I'm calculating a two point correlation function  using highly resolved 12bit images (650,1280).  I am using the following loop to load each image iteratively

```
for c = 0:199;

    img = zeros(650,1280,'uint16');

    if c<10, img=imread([int2str(b),name,'000',int2str(c),'.tif']);end;
    if c>=10 && c<100, img=imread([int2str(b),name,'00',int2str(c),'.tif']);end;
    if c>=100, img=imread([int2str(b),name,'0',int2str(c),'.tif']);end;

end

+ calculate 2point correlation from the same location and averaging over the 200
```

and the correlation function is taken later on.  This calculation takes approximately 7 minutes and it is exceedingly painful to wait so long.

**My question** is it possible to load individual pixels (knowing their exact location for the two point correlation) rather than the entire image? I would like these two be the same for each image in the loop.

I suspect that loading an image two hundred times is what slows down my program and would greatly benefit from targeting specific image pixels to load from each image.

Comment: If b is another iterator, I am assuming the database has more than 200 images that might be needed to be imported, isn't that right? I think you are importing not one but at least 200 such images, that's what I could gather from your code.

Comment: have a look at the [Mathworks documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) it is possible with tif images, there is an example under 'Read Specified region of tiff image' near bottom of the page

Comment: @ Divakar, yes , the "c" loop is imbedded in a loop on "b" which is the index of different folders, each containing 200 images.

Comment: @RTL that looks to be exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

An optional pixel region argument available for Tiff images which specifies the pixels to be read, eg

```
imread('img.tif','PixelRegion',{[rowStart,rowEnd],[colStart,colEnd]})
```

reading a single pixel(or row/column) is possible when the start and stop values are equal.

see [Mathworks Documnetation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) for fuller description, and additional examples

one final consideration
Is it quicker?

```
clear;
tic,A=imread('test.tif');B1=A(50,50,:);toc

Elapsed time is 0.017896 seconds.

clear;
tic,B2=imread('test.tif','PixelRegion',{[50,50],[50,50]});toc

Elapsed time is 0.002447 seconds.
```

yes...

Comment: Things to be careful about - the type of tiff file would play a big role. Tiff's are either tiled or stripped internally (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#Part_1:_Baseline_TIFF) if the required pixels fall within a tile/strip, then at least one full strip/tile will have to be read. So if you read a row from a strip image, you might be fast. But if you read a column from a stripped image, I suspect you might not see a performance win.

Comment: A fair warning, worth documenting however, I assume, it would not apply to individual pixel loading.